# How to retrieve all generic implementations from ServiceProvider in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to get all generic implementations of a generic interface and register all of them using a non-generic interface like below:

```
collection.AddSingleton(typeof(IEventDispatcher<>), typeof(EventDispatcher<>));
collection.AddSingleton(p =>
{ 
    return p.GetServices(typeof(IEventDispatcher<>)).Select(x => x as IEventDispatcher);
});

public interface IEventDispatcher
{
    Task HandleAsync();
}

public interface IEventDispatcher<in T> : IEventDispatcher where T : IEvent<T>
{
    void Dispatch(T value); 
}
```

The reason I am doing this is because I need all event dispatchers injected in a background job runner which is not aware of generic parameters.

```
public class EventJobRunner : IBackgroundJob
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IEventDispatcher> _queueHandlers;

    public EventJobRunner(IEnumerable<IEventDispatcher> queueHandlers)
    { 
        _queueHandlers = queueHandlers;
    }
    
    public TimeSpan Interval => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    public async Task PerformAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tasks = _queueHandlers.Select(x => x.HandleAsync());
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

I understand that retrieving open generics in the way I am doing it is not possible, but I am not able to find a proper solution to this simple problem.

Is there any way to refactor my code in order to make this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works fine, even thou it not the most dynamic solution out there.

Considering that I have a set of IEvent classes, I am sure that the number of IEventDispacher should be the same as IEvent instances. So, I have one dispatcher per event type. Therefore I could simply retrieve all implementations of IEvent and add all respective dispatchers for each of them. The code can be found below.

```
var eventTypes = TypeUtility.GetImplementationsOfGeneric(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(IEvent<>));

foreach (var eventType in eventTypes)
{
    var instanceType = typeof(EventDispatcher<>).MakeGenericType(eventType);
    var interfaceType = typeof(IEventDispatcher<>).MakeGenericType(eventType);
    
    collection.AddSingleton(interfaceType, instanceType);
    collection.AddSingleton(typeof(IEventDispatcher), p => p.GetRequiredService(interfaceType));
}
```

`GetImplementationsOfGeneric` is just a helper method to help me retrieve all implementations of IEvent interface. Below can be found the implementation as well.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TypeInfo> GetImplementationsOfGeneric<TInterface>(Assembly assembly)
    {
        var interfaceType = typeof(TInterface);

        if (!interfaceType.IsGenericType)
            throw new InternalException($"Type: {interfaceType.FullName} should be a generic interface.");

        var types = assembly
            .DefinedTypes
            .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces()
                            .Any(i => i.IsGenericType &&
                                      i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType)
                        && !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface);

        return types;
    }
```

Using this approach I can now delegate the factory call from a non-generic to a generic instance.